# How to update and return a record using an interface in F#

Tags: inheritance, interface, f#

In C#, I am using the following function which I want to move into F#:

```
public virtual void BringToTop(LayersEnum _TopMostLayer)
        {
            if (LayerName == _TopMostLayer)
            {
                ZIndex = 10;
                Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                ZIndex = DefaultZIndex;
                Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
        }
```

Assuming I have the following F# definitions, how is this implemented in F#:

```
type DocumentRadioButtons = ChartLayer | WritingLayer | ImageLayer | TranscriptionLayer | PublisherLayer

module WritingLayer=

type Model = 
    {  Name: string
       Visibility: bool 
       DefaultZIndex: int
       ZIndex: int
    }
    interface ILayer with 
         member this.Name with get() = this.Name
         member this.Visibility with get() = this.Visibility
         member this.DefaultZIndex with get() = this.DefaultZIndex
         member this.ZIndex with get() = this.ZIndex

type ProgressNoteWin = {
       ConfirmState: ConfirmState option
       Encounter: view_doctor_encounter
       LastName: string
       DocumentLayer: DocumentRadioButtons
       WritingLayer: WritingLayer.Model
       ImageLayer: ImageLayer.Model
       ChartLayer: ChartLayer.Model
      }
```

My very FAILED attempt is:

```
let BringToTop rb (layer:ILayer) = 
                   
                     if rb.ToString() = layer.Name then {layer with Visibility =true} else {layer with Visibility = false }
                

                { m with WritingLayer = BringToTop documentRadioButton m.WritingLayer},
```

***Error: The record label "Visibility" is not defined***

Thank you for any help.

#Addendum:

Ultimately, I would like to implement the interface on the different record types of WritingLayer.Model, ImageLayer.Model, and ChartLayer.Model to be used as:

```
{m with WritingLayer = BringToTop rb m.WritingLayer; 
  ImageLayer = BringToTop rb m.ImageLayer; 
  ChartLayer = rb m.ChartLayer}
```

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: The error message means that you probably forgot to `open WritingLayer`, so the record type and its fields are not visible in your scope.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin The problem here is that I will also need the "Model" of the ChartLayer and ImageLayer.  Thanks.

Comment: Wait, so are you just asking how to refer to record fields without opening the module in which the record is defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code won't work as-is:

```
let BringToTop rb (layer:ILayer) = 
    if rb.ToString() = layer.Name then
        { layer with Visibility =true }
    else
        { layer with Visibility = false }
```

This is because F# doesn't implicitly downcast to a type that implements the interface.

**First potential solution:**

Switch from being passed an `ILayer` to just being passed a `Model` directly. Then your code will work.

**Second potential solution:**

I'm assuming that since you have an interface, you want to pass that around as the data type rather than the model type itself. If that is the case, then I'd recommend using an Object Expression to update the data like so:

```
let mkILayer visible (layer: ILayer) =
    { new ILayer with 
         member this.Name = layer.Name
         member this.Visibility = visible
         member this.DefaultZIndex = layer.DefaultZIndex
         member this.ZIndex = layer.ZIndex }
        
        
let BringToTop rb (layer:ILayer) =
    if rb.ToString() = layer.Name then
        mkILayer true layer
    else
        mkILayer false layer
```

**Third potential solution**

If you're fine with [downcasting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/casting-and-conversions#downcasting), you can shadow your first `layer` definition like so:

```
let BringToTop rb (layer:ILayer) = 
    if rb.ToString() = layer.Name then
        let layer = layer :?> Model
        { layer with Visibility =true }
    else
        let layer = layer :?> Model
        { layer with Visibility = false }
```

But usually whenever a downcast is involved that's a code smell, so I'd really recommend constructing a new instance of the interface instead.

Comment: If  I do: let BringToTop rb (layer:Model) = as in the first potential solution, I get the error that "Model is not defined".  (That was my first attempt). :(

Comment: The second potential solution returns  a type of ILayer.  I need it to return the model type it started with. That is, BringToTop will ideally be used as:  BringToTop rb m.WritingLayer returning a WritingLayer;   BringToTop rb ImageLayer with return of ImageLayer; BringToTop rb ChartLayer with return of ChartLayer.  Your help is most appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please see addendum to original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I never could do this the way I wanted to--by using the ILayer interface to update and return the record type it was associated with. I would be most interested in a better way to do this.

What I did end up doing was simply to define three specific functions, one for each type as:

```
let BringToTopWritingLayer rb layer:WritingLayer.Model =
                    if rb.ToString() = (layer :>ILayer).Name 
                    then 
                       {layer with Visibility = true}                  
                    else
                       {layer with Visibility = false} 

                let BringToTopImageLayer rb layer:ImageLayer.Model =
                    if rb.ToString() = (layer :>ILayer).Name 
                    then 
                       {layer with Visibility = true}                  
                    else
                       {layer with Visibility = false} 

                let BringToTopChartLayer rb layer:ChartLayer.Model =
                    if rb.ToString() = (layer :>ILayer).Name 
                    then 
                       {layer with Visibility = true}                  
                    else
                       {layer with Visibility = false}
```

with usage as:

```
{ m with DocumentLayer = documentRadioButton; 
                      WritingLayer = BringToTopWritingLayer documentRadioButton m.WritingLayer;
                      ImageLayer = BringToTopImageLayer documentRadioButton m.ImageLayer;
                      ChartLayer = BringToTopChartLayer documentRadioButton m.ChartLayer}
```

**This seems highly redundant, but it does seem to compile correctly.**

A better answer would be most appreciated.